# Android - как сделать из одного приложения двух иконки на меню лаунчера

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, android-menu

Как сделать из одного приложения двух ярлык в меню лаунчера которое запускает разных Activity приложения.

Например на приложение Google ест двух иконки - 1 голосовой поиск; 2 Google.

Comment: Как то не очень по русски написано - расшифруйте подробнее чего хотите то?

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел ответ. В AndroidManifest.xml для нужных активити добавьте следующее в intent-filter:

```
    <intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> 
<category           android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> </intent-filter>
```

А также установите lable(имя ярлыка) и icon(иконку)

```
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
android:label="@string/app_Launcher"
```